# How to run unit test with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, webpack, mocha.js

I have a Node Js server that I bundled with webpack with the following config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './build/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]',
    },

    target: 'node',
    node: {
        __dirname: true,
    },
    externals: {
        kcors: 'kcors',
        'koa-bodyparser': 'koa-bodyparser'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
                enforce: "pre"
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    // plugins: [
    //     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    //         "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)
    //     }),
    // ],
    devtool: 'eval-source-map'
};
```

This created a single file `main.js` inside `dist`

Everything looks good so far. I manually tested the server and it works.

Now, before I used webpack, I have a set of unit tests that I named with the `.spec.js` suffix inside my entry folder (the `build/` folder) and each `.js` file has each own `.spec` file sibling located in the same directory of the `.js`.

To run theses unit test, I used mocha with the command: `mocha build/**/*.spec.js --recursive --timeout 20000`

Since I am new to webpack and the concept of bundling, how do I run the same tests from the `main.js` file ? I want to make sure that all tests are still passing in the bundled file

Comment: if the tests pass when run against your un-bundled source code, you should not need to run the same tests against your bundled source code.  at that point you're not testing your code, you're testing webpack to make sure it's doing the right thing, which is unneeded.

Comment: There were a lot of problems that I discovered after manually testing the bundle that could have been caught by my unit tests. for example: __dirname was pointing towards the root of my C drive instead of the client public directory. That how I added __dirname to true. My app is pretty big, how can I be sure that there aren't other issues like that due to the bundling without relying on my knowledge of how webpack work?

Comment: Also, I manually figured out that with some configurations, especially in production mode,  webpack may change the name of my classes to a minimified name. My app would break because of that because there are some logics that depends of the class of name

Answer (score 0):

use

```
npm install mocha mocha-loader
```

config your webpack.config.js file like:

```
module.exports = {
entry: './entry.js',
output: {
 path: __dirname,
 filename: 'bundle.js',
},
module: {
 rules: [
   {
     test: /test\.js$/,
     use: 'mocha-loader',
     exclude: /node_modules/,
   },
 ],
},
};
```

then, call your test file from your main file like:
(into app.js)

```
import test from 'allMyTests';
```